# How do I associated custom metadata with a SurveyMonkey survey?

Tags: surveymonkey

I would like to configure my SurveyMonkey account so that when I create a new survey I am required to assign the new survey to one of an editable (by me) list of 'groups'.  I would then like to aggregate reports based on survey 'group'.

SurveyMonkey seems to have a fixed list of 'categories', respondent 'metadata', and per-response 'custom variables', but I'm not seeing any kind of mixed metadata or custom variables at the level of a survey.

Does such a thing exist or is there a common workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to tag surveys. That would be a nice feature to have.

One possible workaround (although not ideal) is to set the Survey `nickname` or put an ID in the Survey title you can filter by when searching for surveys.

Another one is to set a [custom variable](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) on the Survey. Although these are normally meant as GET parameters when taking the Survey, you can use it to categorize Surveys as well.

One last thing is to add a question and use [advanced branching](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Advanced-Branching-Rules) if necessary to make sure it's always hidden to the user, and categorize based on that.

I do agree that a way to tag surveys directly, and then filter surveys based on a tag would be very useful but there is no current way to do that (as far as I'm aware)..