# How Do I add a Category to a new Survey via API V3?

Tags: surveymonkey

I cannot figure out if its possible to assign an ID from `/survey_category` when creating a new new survey via the API?

I noticed on surveymonkey.com when I create a new survey a POST request included a `category_id` but I can't find any info in the documentation. I've tried this:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Authorization:bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type": "application/json" https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys -d '{"title":"My Survey", "category_id": "marketing"}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't currently a way to assign a category to a survey. The categories from the endpoint `/survey_categories` are only for filtering templates from `/survey_templates`.

I don't believe surveys created from one of those templates remain tagged with that category. As of right now there is no "Survey tagging" functionality on SurveyMonkey - although I can see how it can be useful.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267011/how-do-i-associated-custom-metadata-with-a-surveymonkey-survey) for possible workarounds.